# hierarchical ul list collapse with knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I want to clik ul li items and collapse and open them. Working code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nonsense66/Bzekr/)

```
var viewModel = {
    treeRoot: ko.observableArray()
};

var TreeElement = function(name, children) {
   var self = this;
   self.children = ko.observableArray(children);
   self.name = ko.observable(name);
}

var tree = [
    new TreeElement("Russia", [
        new TreeElement("Moscow")
    ]),
    new TreeElement("Germany"),
    new TreeElement("United States", 
        [ 
            new TreeElement("Atlanta"),
            new TreeElement("New York", [ 
                new TreeElement("Harlem"),
                new TreeElement("Central Park")
            ]) 
        ]),
    new TreeElement("Canada", [
        new TreeElement("Toronto")
    ])
];

viewModel.treeRoot(tree);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

html like this

```
<script id="treeElement" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'treeElement', foreach: children }">
        </ul>
     </li>
</script>    

 <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'treeElement', foreach: $data.treeRoot }"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to introduce a flag `isCollapsed` on your `TreeElement` which you can toogle from a `click` binding event handler.

And based on that `isCollapsed` you need to filter out your `children` collection with a help of a computed observable:

```
var TreeElement = function(name, children) {
   var self = this;
   self.children = ko.observableArray(children);
   self.isCollapsed = ko.observable();
   self.collapse = function() {
       self.isCollapsed(!self.isCollapsed());
   }
   self.visibleChildren = ko.computed(function(){
       if (self.isCollapsed())
           return [];
       return children;
   });
   self.name = ko.observable(name);
}
```

And you need to update your template with the `click` binding handler and use the `visibleChildren` instead of the `children` collection:

```
<script id="treeElement" type="text/html">
  <li>
     <span data-bind="text: name, click: collapse"></span>
     <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'treeElement', foreach: visibleChildren }">
     </ul>
  </li>
</script>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GM8nb/).